# Resizing img hover from center and out instead of left side and out

Tags: html, css, image, resize

When I resize my image with the :hover property it does get larger, but it resizes from the left and out, instead of from the center and out...

My code
HTML:

```
<a href=""><img src="cover (1).jpg"class="cover"><a>
<a href=""><img src="cover (2).jpg"class="cover"><a>
<a href=""><img src="cover (3).jpg"class="cover"><a>
<a href=""><img src="cover (4).jpg"class="cover"><a>
```

CSS:

```
img.cover{
height:100px;
Width:100px;
padding-top:25px;
position:relative;
left:290px; 
}

img.cover:hover {
height:150px; 
width:150px;
margin-top:-25px;
vertical-align:top;
position:relative;
-webkit-transition:  2s; /* Safari and Chrome */

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, maybe this is the effect you want to achieve...

```
img.cover:hover {
margin-left: -25px;
margin-right: -25px;
}
```

Comment: This was better than what i was trying to achieve, it made look like it's floatin in front of the other pictures, thanks! Just had to add z-index so it could work, thanks!

Comment: For extra points, use percentages instead so that you're not stuck with a particular size.

Answer (score 1):

If you know in all instances what the dimensions of your images are going to be, you can accomplish this by displaying the image as a block element and changing the padding as well as dimensions on hover.

CSS:

```
a img {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: red;
}

a img:hover {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href=""><img src="" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="" /></a>
```

Here is a demo on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5dMbt/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to adjust the `left` and `top` properties in your `.hover` css. Try:

```
left:-25px;
right:-25px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add either `margin-top:-25px;` or `left:265px;` to `img.cover:hover`